# NodeJS + async: which control flow option to chose?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

As you know, async.parallel, defined with a such code:

```
async.parallel([
    function (callback) {
        callback(err, objects);
    },
    function (callback) {
        callback(err, status);
    },
    function (callback) {
        callback(err, status);
    },
], function (err, results) {
    //smth with results[N] array...
});
```

performs all the tasks all together parallel. However, I need the callback result of first function (`objects`, to be exact) to be avialable in 2nd and 3rd functions. In other words, first step – 1st function, second – ( 2rd + 3rd parallel with results of the 1st one). `async.waterfall` seems to be a bad idea 'cause:

1. In waterfall function can't work parallel
2. I can't get access to every result of stack, only to the last.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Since you don't want to work in parallel (it's impossible to ask for a result of an operation before running that operation) then waterfall is indeed what you want. Or do you not understand the difference between parallel and asynchronous?

Comment: @slebetman It seems so, it would be really appreciated if you explain in brief.

Comment: @slebetman as I suppose, asynchronous code may actually work in one thread, **callbacks** – it's what makes it special. Parallel code works in actual several threads. It's a guess.

Comment: @AlexShest "Parallel code works in actual several threads" is wrong. async.parallel just ensure all the functions are finished before it call the main callback. If a function you passed into async.parallel is blocking, it will still block the functions after it from running until it's finished.

Comment: @howanghk well, you mean, functions in "parallel" are not actually parallel? Lets say I have 3 functions counting big Fibonacci numbers. Every function takes ~5 sec. I supposed if I launch them in async.parallel, the main callback will be initiated in ~5 sec. And if I use waterfall – they will be chained, and it will take ~15sec to initiate the main callback. Am I wrong?

Comment: howanghk is right. Everything in async is simply ways you want to manage the asynchronous code. They don't determine weather the operation runs in a single thread or separate threads. Real asynchronous code either waits for I/O (which you can view as separate threads since most of the time your server on the other end is a separate process sometimes even on a separate machine which is sometimes even in another country) or runs the operation an another thread. The async library does nothing to change this.

Comment: @AlexShest: You can't simply write a function in node.js and call it using async parallel and assume it will be spawned in another thread. In your example both parallel and waterfall will take 15 seconds because Node.js is single threaded. The async library doesn't change that. To make your fibonacci function run in a separate thread you must use a threading library or write it in C (and use pthreads) and load it as a natively compiled Node library.

Comment: @AlexShest: Besides, chaining the functions is exactly what you want. The universe does not allow you to grab the result of an operation from the future before you actually do that operation.

Comment: Thanks @slebetman for the detailed explanation :p
AlexShest: if you really need threads, [Child Process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) may solve your problem, but node is still, by design, single-threaded.

Comment: @slebetman actually I've got it. Please, reply as an answer and I'll mark your one as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need both `waterfall` and `parallel`.

```
function thing1(callback) {...callback(null, thing1Result);}
function thing2A(thing1Result, callback) {...}
function thing2B(thing1Result, callback) {...}
function thing2(thing1Result, callback) {
    async.parallel([
      async.apply(thing2A, thing1Result),
      async.apply(thing2B, thing1Result)
    ], callback);
}
async.waterfall([thing1, thing2], function (error) {
    //all done
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use async. With async you are basically black-boxing your app. Because I don't like the magic for easy tasks, vanilla js:

```
var f1 = function (cb){
    ...
    cb (null, "result from f1"); //null error
};

var f2 = function (resultFromF1, cb){
    ...
    cb (null); //null error
};

var f3 = function (resultFromF1, cb){
    ...
    cb (null); //null error
};


var main = function (cb){
    f1 (function (error, resultFromF1){
        if (error) return cb ([error]);

        var errors = [];
        var remaining = 2;
        var finish = function (error){
            if (error) errors.push (error); 
            if (!--remaining){
                //f2 and f3 have finished
                cb (errors.length ? errors : null);
            }
        };

        f2 (resultFromF1, finish);
        f3 (resultFromF1, finish);
    });
};

main (function (errors){
    if (errors) return handleError (errors); //errors is an array
    ...
});
```